# Python: pip cannot be called after installation

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am using Python27 on Windows 7.  I have installed easy_install and tried to install pip.  easy_install works.  But, pip is not.

I keep getting an error saying:

'The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...' when I type pip --help

I did check the environment variable and Python27 and Scripts were in the path.  I tried to reinstall pip and it says:
'Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...'

It sounds like for some reason it cannot find pip in the list of scripts.  Any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Did you just install pip? If so, perhaps try closing command line/powershell, reopening, and trying again. Sometimes when you update the system path, the command line won't notice until you reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `PATHEXT` environment variable is not configured to consider python scripts as executable. Check whether the PowerShell command below outputs a string with a '.PY' fragment on your computer. If not - well - add this fragment to this env. var. :)

```
 PS C:\Users\blabla> echo $Env:PATHEXT
    .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY
```

EDIT: For the above to work, of course the .py extension has to be associated with python.

Comment: Thank DAXaholic!  I think I still needed to run as admin on PowerShell for pip to work.  But, your answer did resolve some insoluble issues